# How to update Synaptic on 10.10 to include new packages

Tags: 10.10, package-management, synaptic, gtk3

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

I've been using gtk3 on 10.10 to write applications but when I start them it says

`Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`

I have `libcanberra0` installed from Synaptic, but I guess it is asking for `libcanberra3` so I tried installing the `deb` package from the online repository it says it depends on `libcanberra-gtk3-0` which depends on `multiacrch` support which depends on `libc6`. None of these are available in Synamptic, last time I tried installing an newer version of `libc6` my whole system got messed up with unmet dependencies so I do not want to go that route again. I was wondering if there is any way to update Synaptic so it will include `libcanberra3` so I don't have to deal with all of these dependencies?

Thank you,

P.S. I don't want to update to 11 or 12 since my system is lagging so much, and I would like to stick with 10.10.

Answer (score 2):

10.10 is now End of Life as support for it ran out in April.  You can see the release and support schedule [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). You will find it increasingly difficult to maintain this release.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is supported until 2017 however you might be more happy with one of the lighter distributions available (Lubuntu, Xubuntu)

Personally I would recommend Lubuntu on less capable machines, however the much lighter apps may not suit your tastes.  It certainly makes for a very snappy machine however.  Given that you're working with gtk you might want to investigate other issues that may be involved in both of these, for example [theming issues](http://www.techytalk.info/fix-ugly-qt4-apps-on-lubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) with gtk.

Note that Lubuntu 12.04 is *not* an LTS release.  The Lubuntu team have decided not to have LTS releases which means that they are strictly on an 18 month support cycle. I believe the reason is that they do not have the resources to support LTS releases. It would more of an advantage to try Lubuntu 12.10 in this case.

Comment: thanks for the response! In your opinion which would you recommend Lubuntu or Xubuntu?

Comment: I think you'd have to try Lubuntu to see whether it meets you needs.  The main issue would be if the lighter apps don't suit you.  I'm going to be putting Lubuntu on this 900SD shortly to see if runs a bit nicer on the 900MHz Celeron.